# Create PO number automatically in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller

My MVC model will look something like this:

```
public DateTime entry_dts {get;set;}
public string po_number {get;set;}
```

The po_number field will be automatically generated by the system (last po # +1).

How do I ensure that the create controller automatically calculates the po_number when a new entry is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a PO is an ideal unique identifier, it makes sense to also use it as a primary key. In that case, you can simply rely on the auto-incrementing nature of an identity column for this.

If you can't or won't make it the primary key, things get a bit more tricky, as you'll have to deal with concurrency issues. Namely, you will need to query from the database the largest PO number, increment that, and then save your record. However, in the meantime, another record may have been saved, so you'll have to account for that. To make your life easier, you should ensure that the PO column is set as unique. That way, if the same PO is attempted to be used more than once, you'll get an integrity error that you can catch. Then, it's just a matter of doing something like:

```
var lastPO = db.Invoices.OrderByDescending(o => o.po_number).Select(m => m.po_number).FirstOrDefault() ?? [starting PO number];
invoice.po_number = lastPO++;
```

Where `[starting PO number]` would be the first PO number to be issued in the case no invoices had been created yet.

Then, when saving, you need to catch the possible integrity error and respond accordingly. My brain's a bit foggy on the exact exception you should catch, and it seems documentation on handling unique constraint violations is pretty sparse. Everyone wants to talk about *update* concurrency, which is not the same thing as this. However, it's pretty easy to figure out. Just run the code and attempt to save a duplicate PO on purpose. The exception you get is the exception you should then catch. Then, in your catch block, you'll simply increment the PO number and try to save again.

Obviously, this is a bit of an infinite loop (though it would be rare indeed, I think, to have PO numbers being generated so fast that you couldn't get one in on the second try at least. However, I would recommend using something like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to simplify things. Polly lets you set up exception handling policies that enable you to do things like retry infinitely until something finally succeeds, retry and then wait some period of time to retry again, or even circuit breakers, all with minimal effort.